# IntelliJ IDEA v13.1.5 - failure to run svn in /usr/local/bin (svn version 1.8.9) - bug?

Tags: macos, svn, intellij-idea

Hi I'm getting the following error when trying to synchronize with my svn repository with a project already downloaded via command line svn:

svn: E204899: Cannot run program "/usr/local/bin" (in directory            "/Users/xxxx"):            error=13, Permission denied

This works fine from within Eclipse - so why is this error happening?  I have tried everything - chmod a+x on the directories and the svn executable, to no avail.

I am running on Mac OS X version 10.9.5

Please help - if I can't use SVN, I cannot use IntelliJ.

I have use command-line svn unchecked in the preferences for intelliJ

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has this problem - on mac os x - you most likely have issues with the install/version of svn. I had to download/configure/build and install a newer version of SVN and try again - now have svn version 1.8.9 installed, and changed the directory to that svn version in preferences even though the "Use command line client" option was unchecked (also updated the path in my .bash_profile). And it now works!

Answer (score 0):

try uncheking the "Use command-line client" option

Comment: In case anyone has this problem - on mac os x - you most likely have issues with the install/version of svn.  I had to download/configure/build and install a newer version of SVN and try again - now have svn version 1.8.9 installed, and changed the directory to that svn version in preferences even though the "Use command line client" option was unchecked (also updated the path in my .bash_profile).  And it now works!